# Multi column sorting based on grouping and max value

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am struggling with a data exercise and could use some help.

I would like to return the value of column A, based on a grouped value of column B, where the value of column C is the highest.

[My dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuYgU.png)

[image]

Example:

Column B has the value 600001 in the first three rows, and the values 1, 2, 3 in column C.

The value I would like to sort out from column A is therefore 4223900.

I have tried conditioned formatting, returning max values, most anything shy of a manual sorting, but no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: Please, add the image directly to your question (just copy+paste it) to avoid extenral dependencies.
And make your question more clear. Do you need to make a SQL query that returns the desired value? It's hard to understand what you need to achieve.
Are you sure this question deserves the C# tag?

Comment: Sorry, can't add a picture without a link yet, as I am a new member of the site.
I am looking a way to sort my rows based on a maximum value of a group, where the group number and the maximum  value of the group is two different columns.
And yes, the C# tag was a mistake, removed it.

Comment: "would like to sort out" - what does this mean? In what form do you want to receive the result? As a DAX measure? As a calculated column? As a field in a source data?

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure how you need this data displayed but you can create a calculated column using something like this which would allow you to use the data in most visuals:

```
Max Column C Value Per Column B ID:=
VAR CntRowsWeDontNeed =
    COUNTROWS (
        FILTER (
            'Table',
            'Table'[column c] > EARLIER ( 'Table'[column c] )
                && Table[column b] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[column b] )
                && Table[column a] > EARLIER ( Table[column a] )
        )
    )
RETURN
    IF ( ISBLANK ( CntRowsWeDontNeed ), Table[column a] )
```